# ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4, ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4 Could not find ODBCINSTGetProperties()

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unixodbc

ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4, ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4 Could not find `ODBCINSTGetProperties`()

ubuntu 16.04.2  x64
unixODBC 2.3.4
installed unixodbc and unixpdbc-dev packages with apt-get install.
ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4 and ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4  (unixODBC-Gui-Qt 1.0.1 )

I manually edited /etc/odbcinst.ini and /etc/odbc.ini to add driver and system DSN details for my DB2 environment.
I am connecting unixODBC to DB2 and this works successfully with isql.
So I can successfully connect to the system-DSN and run SQL statements successfully at the command-line on Linux to use Db2.

My issue is with the GUIs :  ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4 and ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4, they report "Could not find ODBCINSTGetProperties()"

Both ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4 and ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4 show the registered DB2 driver, but they are unable to configure it because the odbcinst.ini SETUP line library does not appear to have the ODBCINSTGetProperties() method.

The /etc/odbcinst.ini has:

```
[DB2]
Description = IBM DB2 Driver
Driver = /opt/ibm/db2/V11.1.2.2/lib64/libdb2.so.1
Setup = /opt/ibm/db2/V11.1.2.2/lib64/libdb2cfg.so.1
FileUsage = 1
DontDLClose = 1

[ODBC]
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/tmp/unixodbc.trc.log
Pooling=No
```

I searched all files in /opt/ibm/db2/V11.1.2.2/lib64 without finding any that mention ODBCINSTGetProperties() so my question is whether this is something that has to be provided externally (e.g. by someone writing it), or whether unixODBC expects this to be supplied by the driver (in this case the IBM DB2 data server driver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the source code in a snapshot from sourceforge. 
From file odbcinstQ4/CDataSourceNamesFileModel.cpp, it reads:

> - This relies upon the selected driver having a viable setup
>     library. By  *          viable we mean that it implements
>     ODBCINSTGetProperties.

So the answer seems to be that IBM has not provided the relevant hooks in the Db2 driver to allow the GUI tools ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4 , ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4 to operate.  It's necessary to configure the driver via text files instead of using a GUI.